# Create an array from database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

i need help with the following topic:

I'm trying to create an array of users based on their ids

```
  def show
    @appointment = Appointment.where(:event_id => :id).all
    @users = Array.new
    @appointment.each do |appointment|
      @users.fill(User.find(appointment.user_id))
    end

  end
```

First, im getting all appointments which event_id are the same to :id (which comes from the Event table) . Then i proceed to create an array to be filled later with users inside the .each do expression.

The problem is that @users is empty after the expresion ends.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
@users = User.find(Appointment.where(event_id: <id>).pluck(:id))
```

Your code does not work as you misunderstood what method `fill` does - it substitutes all elements of the array with passed object (pretty much like this, might take some extra params to alter its behaviour a little bit). You were most liekly looking for `push` or `unshift` methods.

### Much better solution

If I am correct, your associations most likely looks like this:

```
Event has_many :appointments
Appointment belongs_to :user
```

n that case, you can simply create has_many :through association:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :users, through: :appointments
end
```

Then your query is just:

```
Event.find(<id>).users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@users = Appointment.includes(:user).where(:event_id => <id>).map(&:user)
```

should work, assuming you have the `User has_many :appointments` & `Appointments belongs_to :user` associations setup.